# @WebFluxTest does not create ObjectMapper when upgraded to Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactive-streams

I tried to upgrade [my sample](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample) to Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE, the [PostControllerTest](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/server/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostControllerTest.java) which used `@WebFluxTest` if I do not create a `ObjectMapper` manually, when I run this test, I will got the failure like this.

**BTW: run `mvn spring-boot:run` without a `ObjectMapper` is working**.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:97)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:348)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:82)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$0(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:66)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'restExceptionHandler' defined in file [E:\hantsylabs\angular-springboot2-sample\server\target\classes\com\example\demo\RestExceptionHandler.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:767)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1646)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:758)
    ... 72 more
```

**Update**: When I add `@Import(JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)` to my [PostControllerTest](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/server/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostControllerTest.java), the jackson serialization is working. But some tests still failed. eg.

```
@Test
public void getAllPosts_shouldBeOk() {
    given(posts.findAll())
        .willReturn(Flux.just(Post.builder().id("1").title("my first post").content("content of my first post").build()));

    client.get().uri("/posts").exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk()
        .expectBody()
        .jsonPath("$[0].title").isEqualTo("my first post")
        .jsonPath("$[0].id").isEqualTo("1")
        .jsonPath("$[0].content").isEqualTo("content of my first post");

    verify(this.posts, times(1)).findAll();
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(this.posts);

}
```

When I ran the tests, it failed with the following errors.

```
        2018-11-19 21:20:18.204 DEBUG 6084 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [1d805aa1] HTTP GET "/posts"
2018-11-19 21:20:18.236 DEBUG 6084 --- [           main] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : [1d805aa1] Mapped to public reactor.core.publisher.Flux<com.example.demo.Post> com.example.demo.PostController.all(java.lang.String,long,long)
2018-11-19 21:20:18.380 DEBUG 6084 --- [           main] o.s.w.r.r.m.a.ResponseBodyResultHandler  : Using 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' given [*/*] and supported [application/json;charset=UTF-8, application/*+json;charset=UTF-8, text/event-stream]
2018-11-19 21:20:18.380 DEBUG 6084 --- [           main] o.s.w.r.r.m.a.ResponseBodyResultHandler  : [1d805aa1] 0..N [com.example.demo.Post]
2018-11-19 21:20:18.394 DEBUG 6084 --- [           main] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : [1d805aa1] Encoding [[]]
2018-11-19 21:20:18.410 DEBUG 6084 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [1d805aa1] Completed 200 OK
2018-11-19 21:20:18.416 DEBUG 6084 --- [           main] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [173a6728] HTTP GET /posts
2018-11-19 21:20:18.420 DEBUG 6084 --- [           main] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [173a6728] Response 200 OK
2018-11-19 21:20:18.448 DEBUG 6084 --- [           main] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : [173a6728] Read 2 bytes

java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[0].title"

    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:295)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.JsonPathAssertions.isEqualTo(JsonPathAssertions.java:53)
    at com.example.demo.PostControllerTest.getAllPosts_shouldBeOk(PostControllerTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:515)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: No results for path: $[0]['title']
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.EvaluationContextImpl.getValue(EvaluationContextImpl.java:133)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:187)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:345)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:329)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:292)
    ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@WebFluxTest` test annotation is not importing the JSON auto-configuration in Spring Boot 2.x. There's an existing issue to fix that, see [spring-boot#15070](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15070).

Comment: I have updated my codes, I added `@JacksonAutoConfiguration` to overcome this barrier temporarily, but some tests still failed.

Comment: In this case, `@WebFluxTest` is still not applying that JSON configuration to the server codecs. This is probably why it's not working.

Comment: Just tried to add a `@TestConfiguration` which imports `JacksonAutoConfiguration` and `CodecAutoConfiguration`, but it still does not work.

Comment: If you use `@Import` to import auto-configuration it won't be ordered correctly. `@ImportAutoConfiguration` should be used instead to import auto-configuration and have it ordered correctly. You can use `@ImportAutoConfiguration` directly on your test class.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Replaced with `@ImportAutoConfiguration` in [my codes](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/server/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostControllerTest.java#L38), ran  `getAllPosts_shouldBeOk()` and got the same result. I found the mocked `Flux.just` had not published data in the log `2018-11-19 21:20:18.394 DEBUG 6084 --- [           main] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : [1d805aa1] Encoding [[]]`.

Comment: It seems it is fixed in 2.1.1.

Comment: It’s fixed in 2.0.7 as well